# VHDL concatenate array of vectors to vector

Tags: vector, concatenation, vhdl

I have been trying to implement a method by which i can concatenate an array of vectors to a vector. Essentially i need something like:

```
data_received((rx_length_int + 5) * 8)downto 0) <= rx_ident & rx_length & rx_data & rx_checksum;
data_received(BUILD2_RX_PKT_LEN downto ((rx_length_int + 5) * 8)) <= (others => '0');
```

where BUILD2_RX_PKT_LEN is a constant size, rx_data has a variable number of bytes, but is defined as:

```
type t_rx_data is array (0 to MAX_PLD) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR((ADDRESS_WIDTH - 1) downto 0)
```

I have implemented a few methods, such as a for loop to iterate through rx_data up to rx_length_int, but this has issues with concatenation to data_received as it grows in size... I'm sure there is a very simple solution to this, but I have been unable to come up with one. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For loop is a way to go if all the sizes are constant. Just make sure to define the size of data_received as `(MAX_PLD+1)*ADDRESS_WIDTH + whatever_left`

Comment: Is `rx_length_int` as well a constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of an unconstrained aggregate, `(others => 0)`, which relies on the result type to constrain the range, you can build an aggregate with a specified range, such as `(7 downto 2 => '0')`.

So why not

```
data_received <= (BUILD2_RX_PKT_LEN downto ((rx_length_int + 5) * 8) => '0') 
                  & rx_ident & rx_length & rx_data & rx_checksum;
```

However it's unreadably clumsy. A better approach would be a padding function:

```
function pad_packet (data : std_logic_vector) return std_logic_vector is
   variable temp : std_logic_vector (BUILD2_RX_PKT_LEN downto 1) := (others => '0'); 
-- NB "downto 0" would be an off-by-1 error if LEN is actual length
-- Initialised vhole vector to zero
begin
   temp (data'length downto 1) := data;
   return temp;
end pad_packet;

...

data_received <= pad_packet ( rx_ident & rx_length & rx_data & rx_checksum );
```

Much clearer...

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!